# How to update TextBoxes Data using GridData?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, visual-studio-2019

Regarding the MainWindow screen below, that I want to insert, update, and delete data with DataGrid. I've made insert and delete options for data but I have a problem with the **update** option when i run it an error has occurred.
And the SubID(primary key) in the GridData, I want it to automatically count the number of rows (1,2,3, ...) when i insert new value or when delete a value because as shown below that the mainwindow display the when i insert a new value the the row=35 which is not in order way.
Note: I have linked the combobox(Subcontractor) with the database that on each selection will display the data in textboxes.

[The MainWindow Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzkg0.png)

> The MainWindow.cs.xaml

```
        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;

namespace BV_Desktop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillcombobox();
            DisplayData();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
        public void fillcombobox()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string sname = myreader.GetString(1);
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub where (Subcontractor)='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem+ "';";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {
                txtClients.Text = string.Empty;
                txtDetails.Text = string.Empty;
                txtPO.Text = string.Empty;
                txtScope.Text = string.Empty;
                txtProjectNo.Text = string.Empty;
                txtZIG.Text = string.Empty;
                txtAmount.Text = string.Empty;
                txtInvoiceDate.Text = string.Empty;
                txtStatus.Text = string.Empty;

                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string clients = myreader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : myreader.GetString(2);
                    string contactdetails = myreader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : myreader.GetString(3);
                    string ponum = myreader.IsDBNull(4) ? null : myreader.GetString(4);
                    string scope = myreader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : myreader.GetString(5);
                    string projectno = myreader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : myreader.GetString(6);
                    string zigno = myreader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : myreader.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                    string amount = myreader.IsDBNull(8) ? null : myreader.GetSqlMoney(8).ToString();
                    string invoicedate = myreader.IsDBNull(9) ? null : myreader.GetDateTime(9).ToShortDateString();
                    string status = myreader.IsDBNull(10) ? null : myreader.GetString(10).ToString();

                    txtClients.Text = clients;
                    txtDetails.Text = contactdetails;
                    txtPO.Text = ponum;
                    txtScope.Text = scope;
                    txtProjectNo.Text = projectno;
                    txtZIG.Text = zigno;
                    txtAmount.Text = amount;
                    txtInvoiceDate.Text = invoicedate;
                    txtStatus.Text = status;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        private void btnOpenFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult)
            {
                string filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
                //txtbox.Text = filename;
            }
        }

        private void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Tb_Sub] (Subcontractor,Clients,ContactDetails,[P.O.Num],Scope,[Project No.],[ZIG No.],[Amount(AED)],InvoiceDate,Status) values('"+comboBox1.Text+"','"+txtClients.Text+"','"+txtDetails.Text+ "','" + txtPO.Text + "'," +
                "'" + txtScope.Text + "','" + txtProjectNo.Text + "','" + txtZIG.Text + "','" + txtAmount.Text + "','" + txtInvoiceDate.Text + "','" + txtStatus.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            comboBox1.Text = "";
            txtClients.Text = "";
            txtDetails.Text = "";
            txtPO.Text = "";
            txtScope.Text = "";
            txtProjectNo.Text = "";
            txtZIG.Text = "";
            txtAmount.Text = "";
            txtInvoiceDate.Text = "";
            txtStatus.Text = "";
            DisplayData();

            MessageBox.Show("Record is Inserted");

        }
        private void DisplayData()
        {
            string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

            string CmdString = string.Empty;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConString))

            {
                CmdString = "SELECT Subcontractor,Clients,ContactDetails,[P.O.Num],Scope,[Project No.],[ZIG No.],[Amount(AED)],InvoiceDate,Status FROM Tb_Sub";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, conn);

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Tb_Sub");

                sda.Fill(dt);

                dataGridView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
        }
        /*private void btn_update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = $"update [Tb_Sub]  set Clients = '{txtClients.Text}', ContactDetails = '{txtDetails.Text}', [P.O.Num] = '{txtPO.Text}', Scope = '{txtScope.Text}',[project No.] = '{txtProjectNo.Text}',[ZIG No.] = '{txtZIG.Text}',[Amount(AED)] = '{ txtAmount.Text}',InvoiceDate = '{ txtInvoiceDate.Text }',Status = '{txtStatus.Text}' where Subcontractor = ' {comboBox1.Text }'";

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
           

                comboBox1.Text = "";
                txtClients.Text = "";
                txtDetails.Text = "";
                txtPO.Text = "";
                txtScope.Text = "";
                txtProjectNo.Text = "";
                txtZIG.Text = "";
                txtAmount.Text = "";
                txtInvoiceDate.Text = "";
                txtStatus.Text = "";
                DisplayData();

                MessageBox.Show("Record is Updated.");
            
        }*/
        private void btn_update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text != "" && txtClients.Text != "" && txtDetails.Text != "" && txtPO.Text != "" && txtScope.Text != "" && txtProjectNo.Text != ""
            && txtZIG.Text != "" && txtAmount.Text != "" && txtInvoiceDate.Text != "" && txtStatus.Text != "")
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update Tb_Sub set Cliets=@clients,ContactDetails=@contactdetails,P.O.Num=@ponum,Scope=@scope," +
                "Project No.=@projectno,ZIG No.=@zigno,Amount(AED)=@amount,InvoiceDate=@invoicedate,Status=@status" +
                " where Subcontractor=@sub", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub", comboBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clients", txtClients.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactdetails", txtDetails.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ponum", txtPO.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scope", txtScope.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectno", txtProjectNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zigno", txtZIG.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", txtAmount.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoicedate", txtInvoiceDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", txtStatus.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
            con.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
        }
    }



        private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = $"delete from [Tb_Sub] where Subcontractor= '{comboBox1.Text}'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            comboBox1.Text = "";
            txtClients.Text = "";
            txtDetails.Text = "";
            txtPO.Text = "";
            txtScope.Text = "";
            txtProjectNo.Text = "";
            txtZIG.Text = "";
            txtAmount.Text = "";
            txtInvoiceDate.Text = "";
            txtStatus.Text = "";
            DisplayData();
            MessageBox.Show("Record is Deleted.");
        }

        private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
            DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            
            if(row_selected !=null)
            {
                comboBox1.Text = row_selected["Subcontractor"].ToString();
                txtClients.Text = row_selected["Clients"].ToString();
                txtDetails.Text = row_selected["ContactDetails"].ToString();
                txtPO.Text = row_selected["P.O.Num"].ToString();
                txtScope.Text = row_selected["Scope"].ToString();
                txtProjectNo.Text = row_selected["Project No."].ToString();
                txtZIG.Text = row_selected["ZIG No."].ToString();
                txtAmount.Text = row_selected["Amount(AED)"].ToString();
                txtInvoiceDate.Text = row_selected["InvoiceDate"].ToString();
                txtStatus.Text = row_selected["Status"].ToString();
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtProjectCount_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

> The mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BV_Desktop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BV_Desktop"
        mc:Ignorable="d" FontFamily="Times New Roman"
                Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="BVSubcontractor" Height="740.392" Width="743.887" Icon="/images/bureauveritas_logo.png">
    <Border Padding="10">
        <StackPanel>
         
            <TextBlock Text="SubcontractorName:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <ComboBox  x:Name="comboBox1" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged_1" IsEditable="True" BorderThickness="1" >
                <ComboBox.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="2"/>
                </ComboBox.Effect>
            </ComboBox>

            <TextBlock Text="ProjectNum:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <ComboBox  x:Name="txtProjectCount" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" IsEditable="True" BorderThickness="1" SelectionChanged="txtProjectCount_SelectionChanged" >
                <ComboBox.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="2"/>
                </ComboBox.Effect>
            </ComboBox>

            <TextBlock Text="Clients:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtClients" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" />

            <TextBlock Text="ContactDetails:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtDetails" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" />

            <TextBlock Text="P.O.No.:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtPO" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" />

            <TextBlock Text="Scope:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtScope" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" />

            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="ProjectNo.:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtProjectNo" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" />

            <TextBlock Text="ZIG No.:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtZIG" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" />

            <TextBlock Text="Amount (AED):" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAmount" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" />

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="213*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="95*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- invoicedate -->
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 10 0">
                    <TextBlock Text="InvoiceDate:" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtInvoiceDate" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,36,0" Height="20" />
                </StackPanel>

                <!-- invoiceNo. -->
                <Button x:Name="btnOpenFile" Click="btnOpenFiles_Click" Content="Open file" Margin="429,14,178,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.133,0.651" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                <TextBlock Text="InvoiceNo:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="430,0,162,25" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                <Button x:Name="btnOpenFile_Copy" Click="btnOpenFiles_Click" Content="Save" Margin="60,14,48,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.133,0.651" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2"/>

            </Grid>

            <TextBlock Text="Status:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtStatus" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,269,0" />
            <Grid Height="58" RenderTransformOrigin="0.499,0.097">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="415*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="208*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="68*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--Insert Button-->
                <Button x:Name="btn_Insert" Content="New" Height="25" Margin="10,15,284,18" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.385,1.406" Click="btn_Insert_Click" >
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
                <!--Update Button-->
                <Button x:Name="btn_update" Content="Update" Height="25" Margin="155,13,139,20" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.385,1.406" Click="btn_update_Click">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
                <!--Reset Button-->
                <Button x:Name="btn_delete" Content="Delete" Height="25" Margin="300,12,210,21" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.385,1.406" Click="btn_delete_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridView1" Background="LightGray" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  
 RowBackground="LightYellow" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"  
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BV_Desktop" Height="157" SelectionChanged="dataGridView1_SelectionChanged" RenderTransformOrigin="0.489,1.873"  >
 
                <DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <!--DataGrid-->
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

[The error i got when for example, edit the ContactDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOIFq.png)

Comment: You should post the error message. Otherwise it could be difficult to fix your code.

Comment: If `SubID` is your primary key, it should be autogenerated and managed by the database. You should not show this internal value in the `DataGrid` or at least make it read-only. If you think it is useful to have a row number you can use the `DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle` or the `DataGrid.LoadingRow` event instead, in order to show the row numbers in the row header. You should also remember to wrap disposables like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` into a `using` block.

Comment: Your question needs more focus and corresponding details. Your question is titled _"how to update text boxes ..."_, but the provided details target different problems.

Comment: I edited the code i removed the SubID from griddata and i use "using" statement but still an error occur as shown above.

Comment: This were just general recommendations, not meant to fix the error (I didn't knew the error message). To fix the error, use proper SQL syntax and separate the columns with a comma and use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to build the string (for better readability and simplicity):  `$"update [Tb_Sub]  set Clients='{txtClients.Text}', 'contactDetails='{txtDetails.Text}', [P.O.Num]='{txtPO.Text}', [...]";`.

Comment: Also consider to use a stored procedure to build the SQL command by [making use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#examples) of the `SqlCommand.Parameters` property.

Comment: I did that and it works(the error msg gone) and the message appear that the record updated but still  no change in the datagrid when i did the update.

Comment: Can you verify that the database record was really updated, please?

Comment: It hasn't been updated in the database, I checked it, but when I click "update" button the message appears  that the record  is updated.

Comment: You explicitly show this message. This is not a confirmation message sent from the database.

Comment: Yes, it is , i don't know how to fix this problem because no error occur when dubbing, the problem only in the update column that doesn't change.

Comment: `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected. it should be > 0 for a successful query. Please verify the update statement: check order of columns and if all columns are set. Try adding a space between token and the `=` character. (this lead to errors with certain DBMS in the past). Check database log to get more details why the query was refused.

Comment: I added above the problem with the database that there is unorder row number, how to fix that? please.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? You should not store the row number in the database (in case you are referring to the `SubID` column). That's a UI detail that doesn't belong to the data record (data entity). Make sure this column is read-only and autogenerated by the DBMS and read-only when displayed. You should not modify it. For this reason don't call i t row number anymore, that's confusing. It's the primary key.

Comment: If you only want to update the particular row (currently edited), you must change your query to use the primary key as identifier: `UPDATE [...]
SET [...]
WHERE SubID=1;`.

Comment: I already deleted SubID from the display. My problem now is how to solve the non-updated rows. i have edited the code above but also still no change.

Comment: I have updated the whole project that may help you to know the problem.

Comment: I have posted an answer to show an update example. It uses only the two columns `SubID` (as primary key - non editable) and the `Subcontractor` to keep it short and simple. You would have to extend the example to address your true table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows in a very basic way how to implement the update logic. You would have to extend the data model to meet your requirements (add missing columns etc.).

The key is to bind the `DataTable` to the `DataGrid`. Then bind the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property to a dependency property e.g., `SelectedRow`, which serves as binding source for the editing form fields. The selected item is a `DataRowView`. You can bind each `TextBox` directly to the corresponding column by binding to the `SelectedRow[ColumnName]`. This will update the automatically the `DataGrid` and the underlying `DataTable`.

Use the `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` to update the database using the modified `DataTable`.

For the sake of simplicity, the example is based on a table consisting of two columns: `SubID`(primary key) and `Subcontractor`. `SubID` should be read-only and autogenerated by the DBMS. It won't be displayed in the `DataGrid` and is only used to identify the target row of e.g. `UPDATE` or `DELETE` SQL operations.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    
    <!-- 
      Edit the Subcontractor column of the selected row from the below DataGrid.
      Editing the TextBox will automatically update the DataGrid due to the SelectedItem binding. 
    -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedSubcontractorTableRow[Subcontractor]}" />
    <Button Content="Update Database" 
            Click="UpdateDatabaseOnClicked" />

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SubcontractorTable}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubcontractorTableRow}"  
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subcontractor" Binding="{Binding Subcontractor}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SubcontractorTableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SubcontractorTable",
    typeof(DataTable),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTable)));

  public DataTable SubcontractorTable
  {
    get => (DataTable) GetValue(MainWindow.SubcontractorTableProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.SubcontractorTableProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedSubcontractorTableRowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedSubcontractorTableRow",
    typeof(DataRowView),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(DataRowView)));

  public DataRowView SelectedSubcontractorTableRow
  {
    get => (DataRowView) GetValue(MainWindow.SelectedSubcontractorTableRowProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.SelectedSubcontractorTableRowProperty, value);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    DisplayData();
  }

  private void DisplayData()
  {
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM Tb_Sub";

      using (var selectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdString, sqlConnection))
      {
        using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand))
        {
          this.SubcontractorTable = new DataTable("Tb_Sub");
          dataAdapter.Fill(this.SubcontractorTable);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Update database using a DataTable
  private async void UpdateDatabaseOnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      using (SqlCommand updateCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
      {
        // The actual update query will be automatically generated 
        // by the SqlDataAdapter based on the SELECT command
        updateCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tb_Sub";

        using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(updateCommand))
        {
          SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
     
          // Generate UPDATE query
          builder.GetUpdateCommand();

          int updatedRowCount = dataAdapter.Update(this.SubcontractorTable);
          if (updatedRowCount > 0)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Record is Updated");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it works but an error says that: update requires a valid updatecommand when passed datarow collection with modified rows. in command (int updatedRowCount = dataAdapter.Update(this.SubcontractorTable);)

Comment: Sorry for being late. I am busy... You have to use `SqlCommandBuilder` and invoke `SqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand` to force the generation of the UPDATE query. I have updated the example.

Comment: Its Okay, It helped a lot, Thanks for your effort.